Selenium: Unable to find handler for (POST) session. How to connect to the Selenium Grid from the playwright (java) project?
I'm trying to execute Playwright tests on the Selenium Grid (4).
I have created the remote server (on aws) and deployed SeleniumGrid docker-compose there. Everything is set up correctly since I am executing selenium tests on the Grid successfully.
docker-compose.yaml:
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:beta
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_GRID_URL=http://localhost:4444

  chromium:
    image: seleniarm/node-chromium:105.0
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_GRID_URL=http://localhost:4444

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

There is the way how I have executed selenium tests (successfully):
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver driver = null;
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://13.xx.xx.xx:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);driver.get("https://www.google.com");

And there is the same for Playwright:
    Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
    BrowserType.LaunchOptions launchOptions = new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setChannel("chrome"); //I have tryed both - with chrome channel and without.
    Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(launchOptions);
    BrowserContext context = browser.newContext();
    Page page = context.newPage();
    page.navigate("https://www.google.com");

The ip address Playwright takes from the SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL env, according to documentation. As we can see - correctly since the error says that Playwright tries connect exactly to my IP:
name='Error
  stack='Error: Error connecting to Selenium at http://13.xx.xx.xx:4444 /session: Unable to find handler for (POST)  /session

From another side (Selenium Grid) I have checked the docker logs and I have not found any reaction for my attempts. Except for some permanent error in the logs: Failed to export spans. The request could not be executed. Error message: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4317 but I believe this is another story and not the reason for my issue (WebDriver was connected successfully)
So, if anyone uses Selenium Grid for Playwright tests - please help me establish this connection.
Or there is an alternative to the Selenium Grid for PLayfright?

Can you check this answer helps you

I also got the same error by doing a silly copy paste mistake.
So there should not be any space after port number when you set the variable SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL
http://13.xx.xx.xx:4444 /session

As i see your code after 4444 there is a space, so while setting the URL make sure no space is there
set SELENIUM_REMOTE_URL=http://192.168.0.192:4444 

"http://192.168.0.192:4444 " I left a space after 4444 and got a similar error
so remove the space and it will start working
